# Bernoulli distribution by composition of uniform distribution random variable

Tags: probability

I need to find some function $h:[0,1]\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $h(X)\sim Ber(p)$ where $X\sim Uni[0,1]$.  First of all, what does it actually mean for a function that doesn't get only discrete values to be Bernoulli distributed? I know that $1$ needs to be the output with probability $p$ and $0$ with probability $1-p$.
I was thinking about the dirc delta function, but that only allows me to output $1$ or $0$, but what do I do with the probabilties being uniform?

I will be glad for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will leave some details for you to verify.

Consider the function $h(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,p]}(x)$, that is $h(x)=1$ if $0<x<p$ and $0$ otherwise. Notice that $h$ takes values $0$ or $1$.

If $X$ is uniformly,ly distributed in $[0,1]$ then
$$P[h(X)=1]=P[0<X\leq p]=p$$

Similarly, you can check that $P[h(X)=0]=1-p$.